# Node.js Script for listing all usb storage devices

Tags: node.js, usb, libusb, usb-drive

I would like to write a node.js script.

It will display a message on the console, let's say:

```
USB CONNECTED: usb-name, usb-manufacturer-name
```

ex:

```
$ node.js listubs.js
USB CONNECTED: New Volume, ADATA
```

Ihe only place till now that help me detect that the connected usb device is a usb-storage is the Linux cmd line "usb-devices". But I can't know the user friendly name of the usb storage.

How to know the user friendly name ?

I read about usb-detection, usb npm module, but I can't find what I need from them.
I would like also to make the script be able to mount and umount the usb-storage.

Comment: You can use package usb-detection it give you events when a new usb is connected, change or remove: https://www.npmjs.com/package/usb-detection

Comment: Thank you I have done this using Linux understanding

Answer (score 3):

You might find [drivelist](https://github.com/resin-io-modules/drivelist) helpful. Its a module to list all connected drives in your computer, either removable or not (marked with a `system` boolean property). This is an example output from a Linux system:

```
[
    {
        device: '/dev/sda',
        description: 'WDC WD10JPVX-75J',
        size: '931.5G',
        mountpoint: '/',
        system: true
    },
    {
        device: '/dev/sdb',
        description: 'DataTraveler 2.0',
        size: '7.3G',
        mountpoint: '/media/UNTITLED',
        name: '/dev/sdb',
        system: false
    }
]
```

You can filter the list by the ones that have `system: false` to get the removable ones.

Regarding detecting if a drive was connected, you can call `drivelist` in an interval, and compare the new result with the old one to determine any additions. You can re-use [the following code](https://github.com/resin-io/resin-cli-visuals/blob/master/lib/widgets/drive/compare.coffee) that performs a diff operation between two `drivelist` outputs::

```
_ = require('lodash')

containsDeep = (array, item) ->
    return _.any(_.map(array, _.partial(_.isEqual, item)))

differenceDeep = (x, y) ->
    return _.filter(x, _.partial(_.negate(containsDeep), y))

createDiffOperation = (type, element) ->
    return {
        type: type
        drive: element
    }

var drivelistDiff = (previous, current) ->
    additions = differenceDeep(current, previous)
    removals = differenceDeep(previous, current)

    mappingAdditions = _.map(additions, _.partial(createDiffOperation, 'add'))
    mappingRemovals = _.map(removals, _.partial(createDiffOperation, 'remove'))

    return {
        drives: current
        diff: _.union(mappingAdditions, mappingRemovals)
    }
```